# styling wp_nav_menu - horizontal, sub-menu drop downs

Tags: menus, css, dropdown

[live site.](http://kimberlygenevieve.com/blog/)

I'm using wp_nav_menu called "blog-nav". It's displaying ok, however I'd like to have it horizontally oriented and with sub-menu drop downs(all lower cased items should be in the drop down portion). I've searched around various posts here, alistapart.com, etc but nothing seems to work quite right. I mist be missing something?

Here's what I'm using-

functions.php

```
<?php
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
?>
```

header-blog.php

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="blog-header">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>"/><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/blog-logo.png" alt="#" /></a></h1>
        </div><!-- end logo -->

        <div class="blog-nav"><?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu' => 'blog-nav', 'container' => false, 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>')); ?></div><!-- end blog-nav -->

    </div><!-- end blog-header -->
```

style.css

```
#access ul ul { display: none }
#access ul li:hover > ul { display: block }
```

Any ideas to make this all come together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you din't post any live site with the example of menu, so if I don't get you wrong, then a nice dropdown menu like this:

```
+--------+--------+--------+
| Menu 1 | Menu 2 | Menu 3 |
+--------+--------+--------+
         | Sub Menu 1 |
         +------------+
         | Sub Menu 2 |
         +------------+
```

can be attained easily by using **[THIS](http://pastebin.com/uiNKx7LM)** menu CSS. Though it's raw HTML, CSS, but it's pretty usable in WordPress too. :)

Comment: The link to the live site is the very first line of the question.

Comment: But that's not an example of a menu you may like. :/

Comment: See this category button for an example of exactly what I'm looking for.

http://johnbenavente.com.au/blog/

Comment: :) Then say me you've used the code I've suggested. It's the same thing here. Just use it instead of any menu code.

Comment: I need a strictly WP solution, using the HTML method would create trouble down the road if links were to ever change.

Comment: HTML solution in WP creates prob, No way! Because `wp_nav_menu()` creates HTML in reality. Use it and modify it like yours and then say me it's not working for you. :)

Comment: Please take a look at the live site (link in OP). I've implemented the code you provided - the menu does not appear at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10510/discussion-between-mayeenul-islam-and-user1255049)

Answer (score 1):

You missed the proper stucture of your elements:

```
#access ul li ul { display: none }
#access ul li:hover > ul { display: block }
```

And you might want to position the sub menu to the right so that it wont be annoying when visitors try to hover on the other menus like:

```
#access ul li ul { display: none; position: relative; }
#access ul li:hover > ul { display: block; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what I missed. I've implemented your code, but still my problem persists. Any ideas?